# Error while creating XML file in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, xml, dom

Am reading data from MySQL database and writing it to XML file.
AM getting following error "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. "
Any Ideas how to solve this

```html
private static Document buildCustomerXML(ResultSet _customerRS, ResultSet contractRS) throws Exception 
  { 

  Document xmlDoc = new DocumentImpl(); 

  /* Creating the root element */ 
  
  Element rootElement1 = xmlDoc.createElement("Contracts"); 
  xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement1);
  while(contractRS.next()){
   Element contract = xmlDoc.createElement("Contract"); 

     /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
     contract.setAttribute("ID", _customerRS.getString("ID")); 
     rootElement1.appendChild(contract); 
  }
  Element rootElement = xmlDoc.createElement("Employees"); 
  xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
  while(_customerRS.next()) 
   { 
    
    Element employee = xmlDoc.createElement("Employee"); 

    /* Build the CustomerId as a Attribute*/ 
    employee.setAttribute("id", _customerRS.getString("id")); 

    /* Creating elements within customer DOM*/ 
    Element contractid = xmlDoc.createElement("ContractID"); 
    Element lastName = xmlDoc.createElement("Name"); 
    Element skills = xmlDoc.createElement("Skills");
    Element skill = xmlDoc.createElement("Skill");
     /* Populating Customer DOM with Data*/ 
    contractid.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(_customerRS.getString("Contractid"))); 
    lastName.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(_customerRS.getString("last"))); 
    
    skill.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode(_customerRS.getString("Skill"))); 
    
    /* Adding the firstname and lastname elements to the Customer Element*/ 
    employee.appendChild(contractid); 
    employee.appendChild(lastName);
   
    skills.appendChild(skill);
    employee.appendChild(skills);
   
    

    /* Appending Customer to the Root Class*/ 
    rootElement.appendChild(employee); 
   } 
  return xmlDoc; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating two root elements:

```
Element rootElement1 = xmlDoc.createElement("Contracts"); 
xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement1);
```

And

```
Element rootElement = xmlDoc.createElement("Employees"); 
xmlDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
```

`Document` can have only one top level element. You should create one root element (e.g. "ContractsEmployees") and append the two elements as children. Or you might create two separate documents for each element.

Also, this is not the proper way to create a document (you're using internal classes). Use the document builder.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = builder.newDocument();
```

Comment: Can u please provide me an example with multiple result sets retrieving data from different tables and writing into one xml file.

Comment: You're almost there. Just create one root element and append "Contracts" and "Employees" as children.